# Send small picture

Tags: jquery, radio-button

```
$(function() {
  $(":radio[name='fenstertyp']").click(function() {
    $('#aus3').text( this.checked ? this.id : '' );
  });
});
```

Can I use this function to send a small picture, not only text? how to construct a function?

Comment: What does you exacly mean by _Send_ a picture?

Comment: Do you mean you want to put an image in the element `#aus3`, instead of just text?

Comment: besides, `this` won't refer to `radio` inside your anonymous function. You gotta cache it first (assign it to a variable, then use that variable)

Comment: I want to show the selected image in the other "div" only that I have several different images in a group of radio button

Answer (score 1):

I think he means show

```
$(function() {
  $(":radio[name='fenstertyp']").click(function() {
    var text = this.checked ? this.id : '' 
    $('#aus3').html(text+ '<img src="image.gif" />' );
  });
});
```

Comment: I have a few picture not only one  for example i have group of radiobutton each of them has a picture

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear but you can't send an image with JavaScript through POST/GET HTTP request.

If you want to send the image link you can use the `$('.image').attr('src');` parameter of the DOM object